# Problems with MSSQL IF statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble converting a query from MySQL to MSSQL. Most of my errors are coming from an if statement that's supposed to see how many manhours we have left on a given day. It checks to see if the person hasn't worked yet or is currently working and adds either the amount of time they're scheduled for or the amount of time they have left to work.

```
Round(Sum(IF(mon_endtime > Curtime(),IF(mon_starttime > Curtime(),mon_duration, (mon_endtime - Curtime()) / 10000), 0)),1) AS hours
```

Where mon_ information is stored in the employee table. I'm aware that MSSQL doesn't have curtime() and I have a variable in place to hold it, but I'm having problems getting the correct amount with the following code:

```
declare @cur_time time;
declare @starttime time;
declare @endtime time;
set @cur_time = CONVERT(time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
select @starttime = tue_starttime from employee;
select @endtime = tue_endtime from employee;
if (@endtime > @cur_time)
begin
    if (@starttime > @cur_time)
    begin
        select sum(tue_duration) as hours from employee
    end
    else begin
        select sum(datediff(hh,@cur_time,tue_endtime)) as hours from employee
    end
end
else begin
    select 0 as hours from employee
    end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You cannot use `IF` statements in SQL Server like that, use `CASE` instead.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am not getting your table structure and data . How many rows do you have in employee table? Is it you have only 1 row? as you have a statement "select @endtime = tue_endtime from employee" or else you have same value for tue_starttime and tue_endtime in all the rows? If it's yes then your tables are not in normalized state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this `CASE` statement instead:

```
ROUND(
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (mon_endtime > Curtime())
            THEN 
            CASE WHEN (mon_starttime > Curtime())
                THEN mon_duration
                ELSE ((mon_endtime - Curtime()) / 10000)
            END
            ELSE 0
        END)
    ,1) AS Hours
```

(formatted so I could understand the statement a little better!)